# Which Intel/AMD processor would be the equivalent to the Rpi 4B's new BCM2711?

Tags: gpu, processor-speed, broadcom

My question is pretty straight forward... while I know the specs of the new Rpi 4B say the 4GB version...
I don't know how to really compare its processor to something I'm more familiar with, say regular Intel/AMD processors. Or perhaps a more fair comparison might be laptop/mobile/phablet processors?

I am trying to grasp just how much of a desktop replacement it really is.
For example: Would it be equivalent to say an Intel i3 or it's AMD counterpart? or more like an older Intel core2 Duo?

Also does the Rpi off load some of the processing load to it's GPU?
Assuming, I'm running a headless raspbian install, would the GPU just sit there idle most of the time after booting?

Comment: equivalent in what way? processing power? probably an early pentium

Comment: The computation power is roughly equivalent to a recent Smartphone. The CPU is of a type similar to these of an Android-powered model of maybe last season. It has 4 cores and 1.7Ghz (or close to that), that's about what the cheapest Intel i5 Laptop CPUs have. So in fact, the Pi4 is actually usable as a low-budget PC, for surfing the Web or simple Office work.

Comment: Around a 2004 Pentium 4 possibly, not as good as an Atom 8350